# When the ratio test fails.

Tags: sequences-and-series, analysis

Suppose $a_n>0$ and, for large enough $n$, $\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n} \leq 1-\frac{c}{n}$, where $c>1$. Prove the series $\sum a_n$ converges.

I tried looking at the tail of the distribution, at which point we have a decreasing sequence of positive reals, but other tests don't seem to yield anything. Can't see how the particular form of the RHS helps.

Answer (score 2):

This is indeed *Raabe's test*, and it is a consequence of *Kummer's rule*:

If $\dfrac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}\le 1-\dfrac cn$ for all $n\ge N$, we have
$$\frac{a_n}{a_{n+1}}\ge \frac 1{1-\cfrac cn}=\frac n{n-c}.$$
Now, set $k_n=n-c$. We have
$$k_n\frac{a_n}{a_{n+1}}-k_{n+1}\ge n-(n+1-c)=c-1>0.$$
By Kummer's rule, the series $\;\sum_n a_n$ is convergent.

> *Kummer's rule*
>
> The series with positive terms $\sum_n u_n$ converges if and only if there exists a postive sequence $k_n$ and a constant $\delta>0$ such that, if $n$ is large enough, one has
> $$k_n\frac {u_n}{u_{n+1}}-k_{n+1}\ge \delta$$

Proof of Kummer's rule:

Suppose that, if $n\ge N$, we have $k_n\dfrac {u_n}{u_{n+1}}-k_{n+1}\ge \delta$. This can be written as
$$\delta u_{n+1} \le k_nu_n-k_{n+1}u_{n+1}.$$
Summing these inequalities from $n=N$, we obtain
\begin{align}
&\delta(u_{N+1}+u_{N+2}+\dots +u_{N+m})\le \\
& k_Nu_N-k_{N+1}u_{N+1}+k_{N+1}u_{N+1}-k_{N+2}u_{N+2}+\dots +k_{N+m-1}u_{N+m-1}-k_{N+m}u_{N+m} \\
&=k_Nu_N-k_{N+m}u_{N+m} \le k_Nu_N,
\end{align}
whence
$$\sum_{n>N}u_n \le \frac1{\delta}k_Nu_N$$
converges since it is a series with positive terms and bounded partial sums.

Conversely, if the series converges, setting
$\;k_n=\frac1{u_n}\sum_{k>n}u_k$, one has
$$k_n\frac{u_n}{u_{n+1}}-k_{n+1}=1. $$

Comment: Hmm, is there a more direct way which does not involve non-standard theorems? Do you have a quick proof of Kummer's rule?

Comment: I don't know if there's a more direct proof. Kummer's rule and Raabe's  test  They're among the extra goodies that are  sometimes seen in undergraduate advanced courses.  I've  posted a short proof.

Answer (score 0):

The tail end of the sequence will be bounded above a geometric progression of ratio less than $1$, which is known to converge.

Comment: Did you mean to say bounded *above*?

Comment: @saulspatz Thanks, I’ve fixed my answer.

Comment: Doesn't the statement in the OP imply that the series eventually could grow faster than any converging geometric series?

Comment: To make that last comment concrete, suppose your geometric progression is $b_n = br^n,$ for constant $r = 1 - k < 1.$ Let $N = 2c/k.$ then for $n>N,$ we have $1 -\frac cn > 1 - \frac k2 = r + \frac k2.$ So after that point, $a_n/b_n$ grows at least exponentially and will eventually be greater than $1.$